# How to link a "lists database" with Python?

Tags: python, list, sparql

This is a part of a larger program made to help translating roman dates in our current calendar.

I need to link a kind of "lists database" (all the Roman consulates and their date) as the following

```
def date_():
    if name in list1[Name A, Name B, Name C]:
        date = 509
        return date
    if name in list2[Name D, Name E]:
        date = 508
        return date
    if name in list3[Name F]:
        etc...
```

Aim is that the user enters a "Name" and then the date will be assigned to a variable. Then the name will be searched in all the lists and assigned to the corresponding date.

```
name = input("Consulate name: ")
date = date_()
print(name, " was consulate in ", date)
```

But doing that manually is pure suicide (we would have around 800 "if name in list[]:").

My questions here are

1° Is it ok to do like that ? Or am I just doing something very easy to understand but somewhat stupid ?

2° could I extract in some way the [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_consuls) for having the 800 lists already done with the names and a date assigned ? If no, should I do that in Excel and then find a way to make the lists ? Doing the 800 in Excel will be painful but still less than in Python.
I could also try in a SPARQL in RDF [here](http://romanrepublic.ac.uk/rdf/repositories/dprr/query) for selecting only the consuls with their name and the date of consulate but I don't know how it works...

Thanks for any thoughts !

Comment: can't you keep it in dictionary `d = {"Name A": 509, "Name B": 509, "Name C": 509, "Name D": 508, "Name E": 508, ...}` and use simple `d.get(name, None)`

Comment: write Python script which gets data from Wikipedia - use `requests/urllib` to get HTML and `Beautifulsoup/lxml` to get data from HTML. If values are in tables `<table>` then you can also try to use `pandas` - `all_tables = pandas.read_html(url_to_wikipedia_page)` and later `df1 = all_tables[0]`, `df2 = all_tables[1]`, etc.

Comment: you can use SPARQL for example on [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) to get all Roman consuls: `select ?s where {?s a yago:WikicatRomanConsuls}`

Comment: BTW: you should send name as parameter - `def date_(name):` and use `date = date_(name)` - to make code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because values are in tables so you could use `pandas` to read page and get tables as `DataFrames`

But it still may need some works to join tables and fill empty cells. And when you will have all data then you could keep them in dictionary.

```
d = {"Name A": 509, "Name B": 509, "Name C": 509, "Name D": 508, "Name E": 508, ...}
```

and use simple

```
date = d.get(name, None)
```

---

Simple code which gets all tables from Wikipedia page

```
import pandas as pd

all_tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_consuls')

print('number of tables:', len(all_tables))

for number, df in enumerate(all_tables):
    print('\n---', number, '---\n')
    print(df.head())
```

Result:

```
number of tables: 18

--- 0 ---

                                                                                                                                  Ancient Rome
                                                                                                                                       Periods
  Roman Kingdom753–509 BC Roman Republic509–27 BC Roman Empire27 BC – AD 395 Principate Dominate WesternAD 395–476 EasternAD 395–1453 Timeline
0                                 Roman Constitution                                                                                          
1  Constitution of the Kingdom Constitution of th...                                                                                          
2                                  Precedent and law                                                                                          
3  Roman law Ius Imperium Mos maiorum Collegialit...                                                                                          
4                                         Assemblies                                                                                          

--- 1 ---

                                                   0  ...                                                  3
0  A. = Aulus Ap. = Appius C. = Gaius Cn. = Gnaeu...  ...  Sex. = Sextus Sp. = Spurius T. = Titus Ti. = T...

[1 rows x 4 columns]

--- 2 ---

    Year                Consul prior              Consul posterior
0    509            L. Junius Brutus      L. Tarquinius Collatinus
1  suff.  Sp. Lucretius Tricipitinus         P. Valerius Poplicola
2  suff.       M. Horatius Pulvillus                           NaN
3    508    P. Valerius Poplicola II     T. Lucretius Tricipitinus
4    507   P. Valerius Poplicola III  M. Horatius Pulvillus II[18]

--- 3 ---

  Year  ...                       Consul posterior
0  500  ...                     M'. Tullius Longus
1  499  ...          C. Veturius Geminus Cicurinus
2  498  ...        T. Lartius (Flavus or Rufus) II
3  497  ...                  M. Minucius Augurinus
4  496  ...  T. Verginius Tricostus Caeliomontanus

[5 rows x 3 columns]

--- 4 ---

  Year                   Consul prior            Consul posterior
0  400              Consular Tribunes                         NaN
1  NaN  P. Licinius Calvus Esquilinus      P. Maelius Capitolinus
2  NaN               P. Manlius Vulso       Sp. Furius Medullinus
3  NaN       L. Titinius Pansa Saccus  L. Publilius Philo Vulscus
4  399              Consular Tribunes                         NaN

--- 5 ---

    Year                    Consul prior                Consul posterior
0    300    M. Valerius Maximus Corvus V              Q. Appuleius Pansa
1    299             M. Fulvius Paetinus            T. Manlius Torquatus
2  suff.                             NaN   M. Valerius Maximus Corvus VI
3    298    L. Cornelius Scipio Barbatus  Cn. Fulvius Maximus Centumalus
4    297  Q. Fabius Maximus Rullianus IV               P. Decius Mus III

--- 6 ---

  Year                   Consul prior          Consul posterior
0  200  P. Sulpicius Galba Maximus II         C. Aurelius Cotta
1  199          L. Cornelius Lentulus       P. Villius Tappulus
2  198        T. Quinctius Flamininus  Sex. Aelius Paetus Catus
3  197          C. Cornelius Cethegus         Q. Minucius Rufus
4  196             L. Furius Purpureo     M. Claudius Marcellus

--- 7 ---

      Year                 Consul prior      Consul posterior
0  100[63]                 C. Marius VI   L. Valerius Flaccus
1       99                  M. Antonius  A. Postumius Albinus
2       98  Q. Caecilius Metellus Nepos             T. Didius
3       97       Cn. Cornelius Lentulus   P. Licinius Crassus
4       96     Cn. Domitius Ahenobarbus   C. Cassius Longinus

--- 8 ---

    Year  ...                     Consul posterior
0  1[77]  ...   L. Aemilius Paullus (January–June)
1  suff.  ...  M. Herennius Picens (July–December)
2      2  ...                     P. Alfenus Varus
3  suff.  ...    T. Quinctius Crispinus Valerianus
4      3  ...                         M. Servilius

[5 rows x 3 columns]

--- 9 ---

         Year  ...                          Consul posterior
0    101[134]  ...  Q. Articuleius Paetus II (January–March)
1       suff.  ...                                       NaN
2       suff.  ...                          M. Maecius Celer
3       suff.  ...                                   ignotus
4  suff.[135]  ...       L. Julius Marinus Caecilius Simplex

[5 rows x 3 columns]

--- 10 ---

         Year  ...                            Consul posterior
0         201  ...                   M. Nonius Arrius Mucianus
1         202  ...  Imp. Caesar M. Aurelius Antoninus Augustus
2  suff.[182]  ...                      C. Cassius Regallianus
3         203  ...                        P. Septimius Geta II
4         204  ...                      M. Annius Flavius Libo

[5 rows x 3 columns]

--- 11 ---

  Year  ...                                   Consul posterior
0  301  ...                                  Virius Nepotianus
1  302  ...          C. Galerius Valerius Maximianus Caesar IV
2  303  ...  Imp. Caesar M. Aurelius Valerius Maximianus Au...
3  304  ...  Imp. Caesar M. Aurelius Valerius Maximianus Au...
4  305  ...           C. Galerius Valerius Maximianus Caesar V

[5 rows x 3 columns]

--- 12 ---

    Year                  Consul prior               Consul posterior
0  396.0  Flavius Arcadius Augustus IV  Flavius Honorius Augustus III
1  397.0             Flavius Caesarius                 Nonius Atticus
2  398.0           Flavius Eutychianus   Flavius Honorius Augustus IV
3  399.0                     Eutropius      Flavius Mallius Theodorus
4  400.0                    Aurelianus               Flavius Stilicho

--- 13 ---

       Year                               Eastern Roman Consul
0  535[205]                                 Flavius Belisarius
1       536                          Post consulatum Belisarii
2       537                       II post consulatum Belisarii
3       538  Flavius Marianus Michaelius Gabrielius Archang...
4       539          Flavius Strategius Apion Strategius Apion

--- 14 ---

                  vteAncient Rome topics                           vteAncient Rome topics.1
0                       Outline Timeline                                   Outline Timeline
1                                 Epochs  Foundation Kingdom overthrow Republic Empire P...
2  Foundation Kingdom overthrow Republic              Foundation Kingdom overthrow Republic
3                                 Empire  Pax Romana Principate Dominate Western Empire ...
4                           Constitution  History Kingdom Republic Empire Late Empire Se...

--- 15 ---

                                       0                                                  1
0  Foundation Kingdom overthrow Republic              Foundation Kingdom overthrow Republic
1                                 Empire  Pax Romana Principate Dominate Western Empire ...

--- 16 ---

               0                                                  1
0       Ordinary  Consul Censor Praetor Tribune Tribune of the P...
1  Extraordinary  Rex Interrex Dictator Magister Equitum Decemvi...
```

---

**EDIT:** This code get all tables, join them and save in `'roman_consuls.csv'`

```
import pandas as pd

all_tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Roman_consuls')

df = all_tables[2]
for number in range(3, 13):
    df = df.append(all_tables[number])

# remove addnotations - ie. `[205]`
df['Year'] = df['Year'].str.replace('\\[\d+\\]', '')
df['Consul prior'] = df['Consul prior'].str.replace('\\[\d+\\]', '')
df['Consul posterior'] = df['Consul posterior'].str.replace('\\[\d+\\]', '')

# use value from previous rows (mostly from row in text 'Consular Tribunes') - `ffill` means `forward fill`
df['Year'] = df['Year'].fillna(method='ffill')

# TODO: remove rows with text `'Consular Tribunes'`
#df.drop(df['Consul prior'] == 'Consular Tribunes', inplace=True)

# save to file
df.to_csv('roman_consuls.csv')
```

and later you can read from file and search

BTW: some names are many times in table so I always return list with years or `None` (but instead of `None` it could return empty list and then it can be always use with `for`-loop - even if list is empty)

```
import pandas as pd

# read from file
df = pd.read_csv('roman_consuls.csv')

def date_(name):
    mask1 = (df['Consul prior'] == name)
    mask2 = (df['Consul posterior'] == name)
    #mask1 = (df['Consul prior'].str.contains(name)) 
    #mask2 = (df['Consul posterior'].str.contains(name)) 

    rows = df[ mask1 | mask2 ]

    if len(rows) > 0:
        return rows['Year'].values #[0]

    # it will return `None` if there is no rows

for name in ('M. Valerius Volusus', 'Unknow', 'M. Aemilius Lepidus', 'P. Cornelius Cossus', 'Ap. Claudius Crassus Sabinus Regillensis'):
    date = date_(name)
    print('name:', name)
    print('year:', date)
    print('---')
```

Result

```
name: M. Valerius Volusus
year: ['505']
---
name: Unknow
year: None
---
name: M. Aemilius Lepidus
year: ['285' '232' '187' '158' '126' '78' '46']
---
name: P. Cornelius Cossus
year: ['415' '408' '395']
---
name: Ap. Claudius Crassus Sabinus Regillensis
year: ['451' '451']
```

But columns may still need to clear data before use.

- code doesn't add table `Eastern Roman Consul` which has different columns but still you can save `all_tables[13]` in separated file and use as separated data
- code check in both columns `Consul prior` and `Consul posterior` but you can us e only one of them
- for some consuls there was no year so I use `.fillna()` to get value from row above. Mostly it is row with text 'Consular Tribunes' but sometimes it may be other counsul and this method may gives wrong results.
- some years/names have addnotation which adds number like `[205]` to date/name and I remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Finally I did a SPARQL request in dbpedia to make a csv file, with name and date, that I converted in Excel afterwards. It's a lot cleaner that with panda and Wikipedia. I need to clean a bit the data and then I'll follow your tips for the rest. Thanks again !

Comment: could you put your SPARQL request as anwer ? I never use SPARQL but I'm interested how to use it for this problem. BTW: Maybe other people will also interested to see SPARQL for this problem.

Comment: Sure, just did it ! You can find it below. If you have any questions, don't hesitate I'll try to answer my best.

Answer (score 1):

If in any case someone has kinda the same problem than me, here how I solved the first part (ie taking data from Wikipedia in a structured manner easier to use than with panda).

Basically it's taking advantage from tbe Linked Open Data. Dbpedia is computing a huge amount of data from Wikipedia in a structured manner. This structured manner can be used to make request with SPARQL. For me, aim was to extract the names and dates of the Republican consuls. [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) is a browser-native solution to do the request in DBpedia.

The code I used was

```
select  ?name ?date

where 

{
?consul a yago:WikicatRomanRepublicanConsuls;
rdfs:label ?name;
dbp:years ?date    
}
```

First line is just the names of the two columns that will be exported;
Where is to ask "where" to find the informations we want.

`?consul a yago:WikicatRomanRepublicanConsuls` is to select a specific "folder" (I don't know the good word sorry) in the DBpedia database, ie here all the "objects" containing a republican consul. [These objects are links containing other properties](http://dbpedia.org/page/Lucius_Cornelius_Cinna) (not sure of it works sorry). Since "?consul" is not in Select, this object (ie the links) will not appear in the final resul (I don't care about the links so I removed them directly). I hope it's clear enough, I'm still trying to understand how it works precisely.

`rdfs:label ?name;` is to ask the corresponding name to the "object", and
`dbp:years ?date` is to ask the corresponding date.

Then results were then exported in csv [name, date] and then imported in Excel who made 2 nice columns easy to clean. Thanks UninformedUser for the idea of using dbpedia btw ! And thanks Furas for other tips ! Now I need to clean the data, and then to find the real problem to my question : ie how to make these columns in lists usable in Python !